# Singletons not available when the App comes back to memory

Tags: java, android, singleton

The problem I'm facing is the following: When I start my app all the singletons get initialized in the main activity and everything works as expected. Then if I press the home buttom and comeback to the app quickly everything works, I think it's because everything is in memory yet, but if I go to chrome watch a couple of videos or start a game and try to get back to my app I get an exception. I don't understand this state of the app because it's not killed  but it's not in memory and it tries to get back to the activity it was before pressing the home buttom, the onCreate method is called and I receive the Intent which called the activity in the first place but singletons are not initialized, the exception occurs here:

```
 Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getDefaultTracker();
 tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "My View");
 tracker.send(MapBuilder
                    .createAppView()
                    .build()
    );
```

A possible solution I tried is just checking the tracker and if it is null create a new one and set it:

```
if(tracker == null){
        tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker(trackerId);
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setDefaultTracker(tracker);
}
```

But I get another exception in another singleton. My question is: what variables are kept in memory when the app is in this state? What should I do, maybe call finish when the tracker is null? or Intent the main activity?

Comment: I have the same problem too, it seems that the app is killed if the memory is low and all the static data is gone. I just finish the activity if the static instance that it need is not there. I think I need a better solution too.

Comment: Singletons will be cleared from memory to make space for other app's data, if memory is scarce. Try managing with Shared Preferences of SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply the Android system doesn't insure anything staying in memory forever, whenever the system needs memory it's gonna start clearing background apps and services according to priority.

- One approach is you can make the getters of the singletons handle that, if the `instance` variable in your singleton is null or not initialized, then you should initialize it, that could solve your problem and it will add a lazy initialization flavor to your approach.
- Another is you can add a flag in `onSaveInstance()` and you can check it in your `onCreate()`, then you'll know if this is the first time for your activity to start or it has been cleared from memory and is being reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try using finish() and also add the try catch method in If condition

Comment: I've tried that already but it's not user friendly because you see how every activity in the stack gets killed until it gets to the main activity, I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the variables in memory or just start the mainactivity

Comment: Initialise the variable null